# What is intensity in Poisson (?)

Tags: probability

I am reading [Stoikov's slides](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/IMG/pdf/stoikov.pdf) (slide 15), and there is a statement like this:

> Number of stocks bought $N_t^b$ is Poisson with intensity $\lambda^b
>  (p^b -s)$.

Does this mean that:

$$\mathbb{P}[N_t^b = n] = \frac{(\lambda^b (p^b -s))^n}{n!} \exp^{-(\lambda^b (p^b -s))}$$

?

Comment: Presumably, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The "intensity" $\lambda^b
 (p^b -s)$ is just the average number of events in a time interval.

The term "intensity" is used to indicate "how strong" is the Poisson process under investigation, i.e., the higher is the average number of events in time interval, the stronger (i.e. the "more intense") is the process.

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering whether there should be any dependence on time in my equation